# get telegram user id and forward data to web app

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

i starting creating new function from telegram web app. I trying create web app shop, about to create web app interaction it success. but how to forward data from telegram to web app?

example: a buyer click my product in my telegram bot and add to cart, so when that buyer click web app to modified product and shipping address, how can this bot forward that current cart data also telegram id to my web app server? trying find this documentation in telegram documentation bot api but not found maybe i missed it.